# Can’t sing anymore

Tags: voice, vocal-cords

A year ago I was able to sing what I want and my voice was nice.
One day my voice changed and did not come back. 3 doctors checked my vocal cords and other things, and all results were good (I also did a C.T scan).
No one found the issue why my voice has changed and why I can't sing anymore.
So is it because of a bad technique or will I lose my voice forever?

A Demo 1 year ago:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/15wd59VJf8f0k7lhZeLf6PT7tdvH7CA6v/view?usp=sharing

Today Demo (Unpleasant to hear that)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AG78zFhdmHPZqpS6mORmXv7Un4eVNWv2/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

I'm glad to read you're healthy!. To me it seems like something a good vocal couch or teacher could help you improve quickly. Yes, it sounds like bad technique (lack of good breath support).

Comment: Yeah! I hope I will fix it quickly, it’s stranger that in past I can do it LOL